# Custom site definition to define a custom site with a subsite

Tags: 2010

I want to make a custom site for certain types of users who sign up to my site.

This site needs, in itself, a subsite.

How could I achieve this? Is a custom site definition able to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always deploy the site schemas as two separate features, making the parent site a feature dependency for the sub-site.  When you provision the site(s), create the parent site first, then create the subsite within it.

Comment: Paul brings up a good alternative below.  My solution is schema based where his is template based.  I will say that developing schemas got much better with Visual Studio 2010 and SharePoint 2010, but there is still a ways to go.

Since you are using SharePoint 2010, I wanted to point you to this article I found on Chris Beckett's blog today that walks through creating custom site definitions:
http://www.sharepointbits.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-custom-site-templates.html

In addition, this entire section in the MSDN library may be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the PortalProvisioningProvider, which will allow you to define a site hierarchy.

The following links are for 2007, but there should be something similar for 2010.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566017(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566017%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

http://weblogs.asp.net/paulballard/archive/2007/04/09/creating-a-custom-sharepoint-2007-portal-site-definition-using-the-portalprovisioningprovider-class.aspx

http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/11/10/using-the-portalprovisioningprovider/